# How can I set the Devise secret key inside a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rake, environment-variables

I want to run a rake task, but it's complaining about not having the devise secret key.  I was hoping defining the task with `task :mytask => :environment` would have loaded that up for me but I would need to specify it when calling the rake task.

I keep my secret key in `.env-production` and normally source the file then export `DEVISE_SECRET_KEY`.  But I don't want to have to type `source .env-production && export DEVISE_SECRET_KEY && RAILS_ENV=production rake mytask` just to run a rake task.

I tried to enhance the `:environment` task like so:

```
# lib/tasks/environment.rake
Rake::Task["environment"].enhance do
  if Rails.env.production?
    fn = ".env-production"
  else
    fn = ".env"
  end

  puts "Trying to read devise secret key from #{fn}"

  match = File.read(fn).match /DEVISE_SECRET_KEY="(.*)"/

  if match
    Devise.secret_key = match[1]
    ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY'] = match[1]
    puts "Found devise secret key"
  else
    puts "Couldn't find secret key"
  end
end
```

But it still complains about not knowing the key... is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is enhance seems to be tacked on the end of the environment task, after the error has already been raised, that's why it's not printing any of my `puts`'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, the answer was simple.

I just changed it to this:

```
task :load_devise_key do
  if Rails.env.production?
    fn = ".env-production"
  else
    fn = ".env"
  end

  puts "Trying to read devise secret key from #{fn}"

  match = File.read(fn).match /DEVISE_SECRET_KEY='(.*)'/

  puts File.read(fn)
  if match
    Devise.secret_key = match[1]
    ENV['DEVISE_SECRET_KEY'] = match[1]
    puts "Found devise secret key"
  else
    puts "Couldn't find secret key"
  end
end

task :environment => :load_devise_key
```

Seems to have done the trick!